# L1 regulariser Pytorch acting opposite to what I expect

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I'm trying to add an L1 penalty to a specific layer of a neural network, and I have the code below (in which I attempt to add l1 penalty to the first layer). If I run it for lambda = 0 (i.e. no penalty), the output gets very close to the expected weights those being [10, 12, 2, 11, -0.25]) and if I run for enough epochs or reduce batch size it will get it exactly, as in the output below:

> mlp.0.weight
>
> Parameter containing:
>
> tensor([[  9.8657, -11.8305,   2.0242,  10.8913,  -0.1978]],
>          requires_grad=True)

Then, when I run it for a large lambda, say 1000, I would expect these weights to shrink towards zero as there is a large penalty being added to the loss that we are trying to minimise. However, the opposite happens and the weights explode, as in the output below (for lam = 1000)

> mlp.0.weight
>
> Parameter containing:
>
> tensor([[-13.9368,   9.9072,   2.2447, -11.6870,  26.7293]],
>          requires_grad=True)

If anyone could help me, that'd be great. I'm new to pytorch (but not the idea of regularisation), so I'm guessing it's something in my code that is the problem.

Thanks

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression


class TrainDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    def __len__(self):
        return self.data.shape[0]
    def __getitem__(self, ind):
        x = self.data[ind][1:]
        y = self.data[ind][0]
        return x, y


class TestDataset(TrainDataset):
    def __getitem__(self, ind):
        x = self.data[ind]
        return x


torch.manual_seed(94)

x_train = np.random.rand(1000, 5)
y_train = x_train[:, 0] * 10 - x_train[:, 1] * 12 + x_train[:, 2] * 2 + x_train[:, 3] * 11 - x_train[:, 4] * 0.25
y_train = y_train.reshape(1000, 1)
x_train.shape
y_train.shape
train_data = np.concatenate((y_train, x_train), axis=1)



train_set = TrainDataset(train_data)




batch_size = 100
train_loader = DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)


class MLP(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MLP, self).__init__()
        self.mlp = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(5, 1, bias=False))

    def forward(self, x_mlp):
        out = self.mlp(x_mlp)
        return out


device = 'cpu'

model = MLP()

optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.02, momentum=0.82)

criterion = nn.MSELoss()

epochs = 5
lam = 0
model.train()

for epoch in range(epochs):
    losses = []
    for batch_num, input_data in enumerate(train_loader):
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        x, y = input_data
        x = x.to(device).float()
        y = y.reshape(batch_size, 1)
        y = y.to(device)

        output = model(x)
        for name, param in model.named_parameters():
            if name == 'mlp.0.weight':
                l1_norm = torch.norm(param, 1)

        loss = criterion(output, y) + lam * l1_norm
        loss.backward()

        optimizer.step()
        print('\tEpoch %d | Batch %d | Loss %6.2f' % (epoch, batch_num, loss.item()))


for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    if param.requires_grad:
        print(name)
        print(param)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I use Adagrad as the optimiser instead of SGD, it acts as expected. Will need to look into the difference of those now, but this can be considered answered.